# Writing multipart response in SimpleResult in Scala play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, multipart

I am trying to write an action with multipart response in Scala play.
I should be able to serve the files saved in the resposne as multipart response.

Apart from writing the individual file content headers and writing the files to stream manually in SimpleResult, is there existing API which can be looked into?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean chunked responses? There are a few examples in [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaStream):

```
def index = Action {

  val data = new FileInputStream(file)
  val dataContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromStream(data)

  Ok.chunked(dataContent)

}
```

Comment: No. Not chunked responses. Chunked responses are responses with chunked transfer encoding. And it is used when we want continuous stream of data over persistent connection. Multipart is set of files sent in one request. [multipart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) is used by browser when uploading files.